# MonetDB Write Ahead Logs Not Being Cleaned

Tags: monetdb

As seen in section 3.3 of [this paper](http://www.exanest.eu/pub/2016_RTPBD_Monetdb.pdf), MonetDB is supposed to clean write ahead logs with regular frequency:

> During a server session, the MonetDB server will clean up the log files at a regular time interval (currently, 30 seconds) and if there are sufficient number of changes
> (currently, 1 million ).

I have a repeating problem occurring every few months where MonetDB fails and then during restart there is a large number of write ahead logs to process. Below is a directory listing showing these files (apologies for the order, I had to manually format this):

```
ls sql/
log         log.106086  log.106095  log.106104  log.106113  log.106122  log.106131  log.106140  
log.106149  log.106078  log.106087  log.106096  log.106105  log.106114  log.106123  log.106132  
log.106141  log.106150  log.106079  log.106088  log.106097  log.106106  log.106115  log.106124  
log.106133  log.106142  log.106151  log.106080  log.106089  log.106098  log.106107  log.106116  
log.106125  log.106134  log.106143  log.106152  log.106081  log.106090  log.106099  log.106108  
log.106117  log.106126  log.106135  log.106144  log.106082  log.106091  log.106100  log.106109  
log.106118  log.106127  log.106136  log.106145  log.106083  log.106092  log.106101  log.106110  
log.106119  log.106128  log.106137  log.106146  log.106084  log.106093  log.106102  log.106111  
log.106120  log.106129  log.106138  log.106147  log.106085  log.106094  log.106103  log.106112  
log.106121  log.106130  log.106139  log.106148
```

When starting the monetdbd database loading all these files routinely fails with the following messages seen in `merovingian.log`:

```
2022-06-03 11:06:02 MSG warehouse[3172]: # still reading write-ahead log "/home/warehouse/warehouse/sql_logs/sql/log.106078" 

(70% done)
2022-06-03 11:06:13 MSG warehouse[3172]: # still reading write-ahead log "/home/warehouse/warehouse/sql_logs/sql/log.106078" (97% done)
2022-06-03 11:06:25 MSG warehouse[3172]: # still reading write-ahead log "/home/warehouse/warehouse/sql_logs/sql/log.106079" (38% done)
2022-06-03 11:06:36 MSG warehouse[3172]: # still reading write-ahead log "/home/warehouse/warehouse/sql_logs/sql/log.106079" (77% done)
2022-06-03 11:06:54 MSG warehouse[3172]: # still reading write-ahead log "/home/warehouse/warehouse/sql_logs/sql/log.106080" (15% done)
2022-06-03 11:07:05 MSG warehouse[3172]: # still reading write-ahead log "/home/warehouse/warehouse/sql_logs/sql/log.106080" (52% done)
2022-06-03 11:07:16 MSG warehouse[3172]: # still reading write-ahead log "/home/warehouse/warehouse/sql_logs/sql/log.106080" (76% done)
2022-06-03 11:07:38 MSG warehouse[3172]: # still reading write-ahead log "/home/warehouse/warehouse/sql_logs/sql/log.106081" (40% done)
2022-06-03 11:07:49 MSG warehouse[3172]: # still reading write-ahead log "/home/warehouse/warehouse/sql_logs/sql/log.106081" (64% done)
2022-06-03 11:08:00 MSG warehouse[3172]: # still reading write-ahead log "/home/warehouse/warehouse/sql_logs/sql/log.106081" (93% done)
2022-06-03 11:08:07 ERR warehouse[3172]: #main thread: GDKmmap: !ERROR: requested too much virtual memory; memory requested: 31587172352, memory in use: 243815472, virtual memory in use: 4371382228016
2022-06-03 11:08:07 ERR warehouse[3172]: #main thread: mvc_init: !ERROR: Unable to create system tables
2022-06-03 11:08:07 ERR warehouse[3172]: #main thread: createExceptionInternal: !ERROR: SQLException:SQLinit:42000!Catalogue initialization failed
2022-06-03 11:08:07 ERR warehouse[3172]: #main thread: SQLprelude: !ERROR: Fatal error during initialization: SQLException:SQLinit:42000!Catalogue initialization failed
2022-06-03 11:08:09 MSG merovingian[2681]: database 'warehouse' (-1) has exited with exit status 1
2022-06-03 11:08:10 ERR control[2681]: !monetdbd: an internal error has occurred 'database 'warehouse' has crashed after starting, manual intervention needed, check monetdbd's logfile (merovingian.log) for details'
2022-06-03 11:08:14 ERR merovingian[2681]: client error: database 'warehouse' has crashed after starting, manual intervention needed, check monetdbd's logfile (merovingian.log) for details
```

This can be resolved by manually removing files to avoid them being processed and accepting the resulting data loss but is the only way I'm aware of to start the database once in this condition (see related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71050777/monetdb-crashes-when-connecting-will-not-restart-large-logs)).

My question is, is there a way to prevent this, maybe in config somewhere? If I could tell MonetDB to clean these logs more frequently and save the data to the database this would prevent the issue. Alternatively, is there a manual command that could be used? Currently cleaning sql logs is happening on a scale of every few weeks or possibly not at all, far from the 30 seconds mentioned in the paper linked at the beginning of this post.

Thanks,

James

Comment: Hi James! Could you tell us which version of MonetDB you are using? And on which platform?

Comment: Hi Joeri, it's MonetDB Database Server v11.39.17 (Oct2020-SP5) on Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS. Many thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your comment you mention that you are running MonetDB Oct2020-SP5. That's a rather old, unsupported version.

The accumulation of log files is probably due to MonetDB not being able to get 'time to breath' and apply the changes in the log to its stable storage. In the Jul2021 release, MonetDB's transaction layer has been completely revised and this should be much less of a problem.

I recommend upgrading to a more recent version such as the Jan2022-SP3 release and checking the behavior of that version under your workload.

Comment: OK, thanks Joeri, I'll implement this and post back with results. It might take me a few days to organise.

Comment: Hi @Joeri van Ruth, I now have the DB upgraded to the following version: MonetDB Database Server v11.43.15. I'll monitor and post back if the write ahead logs are still building up. Thanks!

Comment: Accepting answer as this long running issue has not reoccurred